# How to traverse an HTML document loaded using iframe?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I want to traverse the content of inframe, which is a separate HTML document api.php.

For example, I want the INNER MOST paragraph with class c2. How would I traverse it?

You may think of a way of using any `jQuery` method which would find that element by finding the Matching Text of that paragraph, but assume that you can't access it. Is there any way to traverse it?

Further, I have used `setTimeout` so that the document is loaded first and then the methods would work. But I don't want this delay every time. First time is okay, but then I want it like a normal document which is loaded first time and available until reload.

Here's the code:

**radio.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
            var elem=$(".c1 iframe").contents().find('html').find('body');

            //ABOVE METHOD REACHES ONLY A SPECIFIC ELEMENT, BUT I WANT IT TO TRAVERSE IT LIKE FOLLOWING WAY:

            $("elem div p").click();

        }, 1000);

    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="c1">
  <iframe src="api.php" height="200" width="300">
  </iframe>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**api.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="c1"></div>
    <div class="c1">
        <p class="c2"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="c1">
        <p class="c2"></p>
        <p class="c2">
            <p class="c2">INNER MOST</p>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the inner element?

Comment: I wonder why the admins here are so over confident without reading the details of this question. The duplicate isn't working for me. `iframeWindow.$("my element > elem")` not working, although iframeWindow is not null.

Comment: @charlietfl want to change the `css`.